# What type of test should be used in the case of many independent variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

First of all, it was difficult for me to find a proper title for the question that I am asking here.

I have the following data:

```
Class       Branch  LA_type Method_type     Method_call     Branch_type     Branch_condition    Tested_parameter
Goal        12      Smooth  public static   never called    IFNE            TRUE                 String
TreeApp     20      Rugged  constructor     none            IF_ICMPGE  FALSE                     int
Password    4       Smooth  private         never called    IFEQ    FALSE                        int
XMLParser   9       Rugged  constructor     none            IFNONNULL   TRUE                     String
MapClass    33      Smooth  public          never called    IFGT    FALSE                        double
```

I want to know which of the variables (`Method_type`, `Method_call`, `Branch_type`, `Branch_condition`, or `Tested_parameter`) have an impact on the `LA_type` of each branch. For example, does the `Method_type` make the branch smooth or rugged? I need to ask the same question with the other variables. It is obvious that the `Method_type` and `Method_call` have an impact on the `LA_type` of each branch, since the constructor method type leads to rugged branch and a never called method leads to a smooth branch.

How can I answer such a question statically? In other words, what type of test is better to use to find out whether each variable has a significant correlation with the `LA_type`? Does the Kruskal–Wallis test work in this case?

Comment: Are you saying you wish to model `LA_type` as a function of the *six* other variables based on only these *five* records?

Comment: @whuber this is just a sample. In reality, I have hundreds of records.

Comment: Okay--but that's not what you have written.  Regardless, search our site for [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic+regression).

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry how can the logistic regression help?

Comment: It is the procedure of choice for analyzing how a binary response depends on other variables.